# Unknown Syntax Error: Unexpected token var

Tags: javascript

I'm stumped while working on a leetcode problem, the following Javascript code throws me the syntax error: Line 33: SyntaxError: Unexpected token var. My code may be wrong for the leetcode problem, but I'm specifically asking where my Syntax has gone wrong.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.next = null;
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
    let list = new ListNode(0);
    let head = list;
    let carry = 0;
    while (l1.next != null || l2.next != null){
        let x = l1.val;
        let y = l2.val;
        if (x + y > 9){
            list.val = ((x + y) % 10) + carry;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            list.val = x + y + carry;
            carry = 0;
        }
        list = list.next;
        l1 = l1.next;
        l2 = l2.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: And where is the line 33? This snippet has no syntax errors.

Comment: The problem is probably before the code you posted.

Comment: The error definately isn't in the code you posted here.

Comment: Line 33 is after line 32: 'return head;'
I thought it didn't have syntax error, but it still throws Unexpected token var at me
EDIT: That's line 31, line 32 is the bracket

Comment: Then you have to check the following (but not empty) line.

Comment: According to my math, line `return head;` is line 31. That makes line 33 the line that comes after the code you posted here.

Comment: Yeah you're right Felix, I just remembered that the error referred to the line after my code, which I haven't written as it's on leetcode, I think its missing semi-colon on like 32 like answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a semicolon at the end of the function definitions:

```
var func = function(){

}; // <- check here
```

notice the semicolon at the end.
possibly missing in some code that was not included in your response, which may include *another* function definition.

HTH

---

```js
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
    let list = new ListNode(0);
    let head = list;
    let carry = 0;
    while (l1.next != null || l2.next != null){
        let x = l1.val;
        let y = l2.val;
        if (x + y > 9){
            list.val = ((x + y) % 10) + carry;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            list.val = x + y + carry;
            carry = 0;
        }
        list = list.next;
        l1 = l1.next;
        l2 = l2.next;
    }
    return head;
}; // <------------ here
```

Comment: Although better style, that omission would not cause this error.

Comment: For some reason, it did fix it on leetcode. I'm sure it's caused from how they test my code, though I'm a beginner and don't understand how they do, heh..

Comment: Glad I could help!