# Odd issues in Appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I had to recreate a tool my company uses, as the last guy who created it left the code a huge mess. A large portion of this is copied from his pre-existing (more importantly, working) script. I'm unsure why I'm getting these errors, would someone please help a nooooooob like myself?

Issue 1:
"Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var' line: 89 file: Code.gs"
It doesn't matter where I put the /*  */, this whole section returns the error. Most everything above is stating variables.

```
if (location === 'L1'){
    var officeLocation = 'Drive Folder ID 1';
    var emailRecip = 'L1 group email address';
    var franchiseNum = 'L1 franchise #';
    createFolderStructure(officeLocation);
    writeDash(pittDash,custFN,custLN,date,leadType);  //These variables are all defined in code above
    marketing(location zip,referSource);
    if(leadType==='Assessment'){  
      writeDash(wSheet,custFN,custLN,date,leadType)
      }

  } else if (location === 'L2'){
    var officeLocation = 'You get the picture';
    var emailRecip = 'I am just going to redact with -----';  
    var franchiseNum = '-----';
    createFolderStructure(officeLocation);
    writeDash(pittDash,custFN,custLN,date,leadType);
    if(leadType==='Assessment'){
      writeDash(wSheet,custFN,custLN,date,leadType)
      }

  } else if (location === '----'){
       var officeLocation = '-----';
    var emailRecip = '------';
    var franchiseNum = '------';
    createFolderStructure(officeLocation);
    writeDash(pittDash,custFN,custLN,date,leadType);
    if(leadType==='Assessment'){
      writeDash(wSheet,custFN,custLN,date,leadType)
      }
  } else {
    var emailBdy = 'Looks like you forgot to set a location to that last ----, Try Again!'
    var emailSubject = 'Uh-Oh!!'
    var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,emailSubject,emailBdy);
    return;
  }

//#- Send ---- Email - must be after [6- Create Drive Folders]
  
  var emailSubj = '----: '+ franchiseNum + ' - '+custLN+', '+custFN+' - '+lossType+lossClass+'-'+date;
  var emailBody = custFN+' '+custLN+'\n'+'\n'+ leadType+ '\n'+lossType+'\n'+lossType+'\n'+custPhone+'\n'+clientAddress+'\n'+'\n'+leadDesc+'\n'+'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/'+officeLocation;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailRecip,emailSubj,emailBody);
  Logger.log(emailBody);


}
```

Issue 2:
"Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input line: 161 file: Code.gs"
This seems to just not want me to close the function. Tried multiple times, not sure why it's not working. Only seems to be on this block. This is the last function in the code.

```
function marketing(location, zip,referSource){
  var mSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(location + ' Marketing');
  mSheetName.insertRowsAfter(29);
  mSheetName.getRange('A30').setValue(referSource);
  mSheetName.getRange('C30').setValue(zip);
  mSheetName.getRange('B30').setValue(1);
  mSheetName.getRange('B30').setValue(1);
}
```

I've tried re-typing, googling for about half an hour, re-typing again, re-writing. I feel like my issue is blindingly simple, please help :D

Whole Code Body (Redacted):

```js
function theButton() {
//1- Sheet Variables v(spreadsheet, newJobSheet,fOneDash,fTwoDash,fThreeDash,fOneMark,fTwoMark)
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var newJobSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('New Job');
  var fOneDash = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('franchOne Dash');
  var fTwoDash = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('franchTwo Dash');
  var fThreeDash = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('fThree Dash');
  var fOneMark = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('franchOne Marketing');
  var fTwoMark = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('franchTwo Marketing');



//2- Input Variables v(location,leadType,custFN,custLN,lossType,lossClass,custPhone,stAdd,cityState,zip,referSource,leadDesc)
  var location = newJobSheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var leadType = newJobSheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  var custFN = newJobSheet.getRange('B4').getValue();
  var custLN = newJobSheet.getRange('B5').getValue();
  var lossType = newJobSheet.getRange('B6').getValue();
  var lossClass = newJobSheet.getRange('B7').getValue();
  var custPhone = newJobSheet.getRange('B8').getValue();
  var stAdd = newJobSheet.getRange('B9').getValue();
  var cityState = newJobSheet.getRange('B10').getValue();
  var zip = newJobSheet.getRange('B11').getValue();
  var referSource = newJobSheet.getRange('B12').getValue();
  var leadDesc = newJobSheet.getRange('B13').getValue();


//3- Compiled variables v(clientAddress,clientAddressURL,userEmail)
  var clientAddress = stAdd + '\n' + cityState + " " + zip;
  var clientAddressURL = stAdd + ' ' + cityState + " " + zip;
  Logger.log(clientAddressURL);
  let newAddress = '0';
  Logger.log(newAddress);
  newAddress = parseAddressURL(clientAddressURL);
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();








//4- Date v(date, month, year)
  var date = newJobSheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var month = newJobSheet.getRange('A50').getValue();
  var year = newJobSheet.getRange('A51').getValue();


//5- Job Name v(nameNewJob)
  var nameNewJob = custLN + ', ' + custFN + ', ' + lossType + ', ' + lossClass + ', ' + leadDesc +




//6- Create Drive Folders, write to Dash, Marketing, Assessment Tracker v(officeLocation [driveID],emailRecip,franchiseNum)


if (location === 'franchOne'){
    var officeLocation = 'driveurl(thisisredacted)';
    var emailRecip = 'franchOne@emailaddress.com';
    var franchiseNum = ‘franchOneNum';
    createFolderStructure(officeLocation);
    writeDash(fOneDash,custFN,custLN,date,leadType);
    marketing(location zip,referSource);
    if(leadType==='Assessment'){
      writeDash(wSheet,custFN,custLN,date,leadType)
      }


  } else if (location === 'franchTwo'){
    var officeLocation = 'driveurl(thisisredacted)';
    var emailRecip = 'franchTwo@emailaddress.com';  
    var franchiseNum = 'fTwoFranchNum ';
    createFolderStructure(officeLocation);
    writeDash(fOneDash,custFN,custLN,date,leadType);
    if(leadType==='Assessment'){
      writeDash(wSheet,custFN,custLN,date,leadType)
      }


  } else if (location === 'fThree'){
       var officeLocation = 'driveurl(thisisredacted)';
    var emailRecip = 'franchTree@emailaddress.com';
    var franchiseNum = 'fThree ';
    createFolderStructure(officeLocation);
    writeDash(fOneDash,custFN,custLN,date,leadType);
    if(leadType==='Assessment'){
      writeDash(wSheet,custFN,custLN,date,leadType)
      }
  } else {
    var emailBdy = 'Looks like you forgot to set a location to that last FNOL, Try Again!'
    var emailSubject = 'Uh-Oh!!'
    var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,emailSubject,emailBdy);
    return;
  }


//#- Send FNOL Email - must be after [6- Create Drive Folders]
  
  var emailSubjFNOL = 'FNOL: '+ franchiseNum + ' - '+custLN+', '+custFN+' - '+lossType+lossClass+'-'+date;
  var emailBody = custFN+' '+custLN+'\n'+'\n'+ leadType+ '\n'+lossType+'\n'+lossType+'\n'+custPhone+'\n'+clientAddress+'\n'+'\n'+leadDesc+'\n'+'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/'+officeLocation;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailRecip,emailSubjFNOL,emailBody);
  Logger.log(emailBody);




};










function createFolderBasic(folderID, folderName) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var newFolder = folder.createFolder(folderName);
  return newFolder.getId();
  };








function createFolderStructure(officeLocation){
    var newClientFolderID = createFolderBasic(officeLocation, nameNewJob);
    var newClientMitID = createFolderBasic(newClientFolderID, 'MIT');
    var newClientPhotosID = createFolderBasic(newClientFolderID, 'Photos');
    var newClientReconID = createFolderBasic(newClientFolderID, 'RECON');
    var newClientReconActiveEstimatesID = createFolderBasic(newClientReconID, 'Active Estimates');
    var newClientReconArchivedID = createFolderBasic(newClientReconID, 'Archived');
    var newClientReconBidsID = createFolderBasic(newClientReconID, 'Sub Bids');
    var newClientReconFormsID = createFolderBasic(newClientReconID, 'Forms');
  };
function parseAddressURL(newClientAddressURL,) {
  var address = newClientAddressURL
  var address = address.replace(/ /g, '+' );
  address = address.replace(/,/g , '%2C');
  Logger.log(address)
  var addressURL = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=' + address;
  Logger.log(address);
  Logger.log(addressURL);
  return addressURL;
  };


function writeDash(wSheet,custFN,custLN,date,leadType){
    wSheet.insertRowsAfter(2,1);
    wSheet.getRange('A2').setValue(custFN);
    wSheet.getRange('B2').setValue(custLN);
    wSheet.getRange('C2').setValue(date);
    wSheet.getRange('D2').setValue(leadType);
  };


  function assTrack(custFN,custLN,date,custPhone,location,leadDesc,newAddress){
      var assss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/driveurl(thisisredacted)');
      var assLog = assss.getSheetByName('Assessment Log');
      assLog.insertRowBefore(2);
      assLog.getRange('A2').setValue(custFN);
      assLog.getRange('B2').setValue(custLN);
      assLog.getRange('C2').setValue(date);
      assLog.getRange('D2').setValue(custPhone);
      assLog.getRange('E2').setValue(location);
      assLog.getRange('F2').setValue(newAddress);
      assLog.getRange('G2').setValue(leadDesc);
  };




function marketing(location, zip,referSource){
  var mSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(location + ' Marketing');
  mSheetName.insertRowsAfter(29);
  mSheetName.getRange('A30').setValue(referSource);
  mSheetName.getRange('C30').setValue(zip);
  mSheetName.getRange('B30').setValue(1);
  mSheetName.getRange('B30').setValue(1);
};
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please post the entire code.gs per your Project editor. There are ways to identify the error that you have received, such as [Unknown Syntax Error: Unexpected token var](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47066507/1330560) (read the comments), but unless we can calculate which line is #89 and #161 we're just working blind.

Comment: I was trying to avoid redacting the whole thing, but I realize now it's necessary. The issue shows up with the first 'if' statement.

Comment: Okay, so I was dumb.. When I finished stating the variable above the if statement, everything works properly. Thanks for your help!